# PHP native functions in native code or in interpreted code?

Tags: php

I'd like to know if the native PHP functions are actually programmed in C, meaning any native function will probably be faster than homemade ones equivalent, or if it uses somes PHP scripts always included in all pages with thoses functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/php) (it took me less seconds to google it than to write this comment)

Comment: They are coded in C. You can find the source code here https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: Thanks to have answered. I didn't find mention of them in the php src (as I am far from C specialist). Looks obvious because, well, PHP is made in C but wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, PHP and its extensions are implemented in C.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you worry that much about performance? Yes, PHP and its extensions are implemented in C. Do you have any performance critical application? You can always have a look at APC and Facebook's HipHop:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP